# Find clusters of industrial probe

Tags: python, clustering, data-science-model

I'm new to data science, but in these last months i have started to gather many samples of values coming from different industrial probes (temperature of water, pression, Kw consumed, etc). I have developed a procedure to collect every 5 seconds many different values from many differents PLCs, and I have now about 40M records of data. After doing some basic analysis and visualization, I would like to start by finding for every probe the clusters of data and of course the outliers, so I can understand when I have a "strange" situation. Can you help me giving some advise to what kind of analysis I can try to do?

Sorry, I understand the question could seem quite vague, but I'm really at the beginning and trying to undestand something more about my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dimensional reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) like [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [PacMap](https://github.com/YingfanWang/PaCMAP) is a good way to understand complex and numerous data.

Here is a [demonstrator](https://projector.tensorflow.org/).

Nevertheless, 40M is a lot of data: you may not see clear clusters if you take all the data at once, and it might be useless: a lot of industrial cases focus on a time frame, and taking all the data would result in a blurred visualization.

I recommend starting with a ~1000 values data sample (ex: 1 day), and then increase progressively. You'll be able to detect outliers that are outside the clusters.

In addition, you can also apply some [PCA](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.09-principal-component-analysis.html) to understand some data dependency linearly.

Here is a similar case to yours:

https://github.com/bharathsudharsan/Air-Quality-IoT-Analytics